# Sequelize throws Error "Unable to find a valid association for model x" When Ordering By Associated Model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a problem with sequelize, when I want to ordering my query result by associated model, sequelize throw this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Unable to find a valid association for model, 'productLanguage'

*These are my files:*

**Context.js **

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/sampleDB");

module.exports = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sequelize
}
```

**User.js**

```
const context = require('../context');

module.exports = context.sequelize.define('user', {
    name: context.Sequelize.STRING,
    },{
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

**Product.js**

```
const context = require('../context');

module.exports = context.sequelize.define('product', {
    slug: context.Sequelize.STRING,
    price: context.Sequelize.DECIMAL(10,2),
    },{
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

**ProductLanguage.js**

```
const context = require('../context');

module.exports = context.sequelize.define('productLanguage', {
    name: context.Sequelize.STRING,
    },{
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
});
```

**Language.js**

```
const context = require('../context');

module.exports = context.sequelize.define('language', {
    name: context.Sequelize.STRING,
    slug: context.Sequelize.STRING,
    },{
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

**db.js**

```
var context = require('./context');
var User = require('./models/User'),
    Product = require('./models/Product'),
    ProductLanguage = require('./models/ProductLanguage'),
    Language = require('./models/Language');


// ===================== ASSOCIATIONS =====================
// user 1:m Product
Product.belongsTo(User); // product owner
User.hasMany(Product);

// Product 1:m ProductLanguage m:1 Language
ProductLanguage.belongsTo(Product);
Product.hasMany(ProductLanguage);
ProductLanguage.belongsTo(Language);
Language.hasMany(ProductLanguage);

module.exports = {
    Sequelize: context.Sequelize,
    sequelize: context.sequelize,
    models: {
        Product: Product,
        User: User,
        ProductLanguage: ProductLanguage,
        Language: Language
    }
}
```

*and finally this is my query*

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next)=>{

    var result = await db.models.User.findAll({
        include:[
            {
                model: db.models.Product,
                attributes: ['price'],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.models.ProductLanguage,
                        attributes: ['name'],
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: db.models.Language, 
                                attributes: ['name'],                               
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        order:[
            [db.models.ProductLanguage, 'name', 'desc']
        ],
        attributes: ['name']
    });

    res.send(result);
});
```

The query work fine without "order" part, so I think the problem should be one on these :

1. Something is wrong on this part: [db.models.ProductLanguage, 'name', 'desc']
2. Something is wrong on association definitions

Note: I've searched on youtube and stackoverflow and sequelize documentation over 4 days but nothing found.

I use these dependencies:

```
"express": "^4.16.2",
"pg": "^6.4.2",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
"sequelize": "^4.32.2"
```

Answer (score 24):

I've found the solution.

*I must put all associated model into order, so the correct query is:*

```
order:[
        [db.models.Product, db.sequelize.models.ProductLanguage, 'name', 'desc']
    ],
```

*The full query must be:*

```
var result = await db.models.User.findAll({
    include:[
        {
            model: db.models.Product,
            attributes: ['price'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.models.ProductLanguage,
                    attributes: ['name'],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.models.Language, 
                            attributes: ['name'],                               
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    order:[
        [db.models.Product, db.sequelize.models.ProductLanguage, 'name', 'desc']
    ],
    attributes: ['name']
});
```

**I hope this will be helpful for others.**

Comment: Also if you have an association with an alias, you must specify the alias as well, for example: `order:[[db.models.Product, { model: db.models.ProductLanguage, as: 'language_of_product' } , 'name', 'desc']]`

Comment: With respect to above example:
You don't need to mention the model before the object if you are using alias
So the query becomes -
order:[[{ model: db.models.ProductLanguage, as: 'language_of_product' } , 'name', 'desc']]

Answer (score 5):

Those who still won't get the result, try this syntax -

```
order:[[{ model: db.models.ProductLanguage, as: 'language_of_product' } , 'name', 'desc']]
```

Comment: Indeed, if there is an alias specified in the include, it needs to be present in the order's model as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Moradof's answer, it's important to note that if you specify an alias for your included model, then you must also specify the alias in the `order` statement.

Building on the previous example, we get:

```
var result = await db.models.User.findAll({
    include:[
        {
            model: db.models.Product,
            as: 'include1',
            attributes: ['price'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.models.ProductLanguage,
                    as: 'include2',
                    attributes: ['name'],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.models.Language, 
                            attributes: ['name'],                               
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    order:[
        [{ model: db.models.Product, as: 'include1' }, 
         { model: db.sequelize.models.ProductLanguage, as: 'include2' },
         'name',
         'desc']
    ],
    attributes: ['name']
});
```

Note that because I named the `Product` as `include1` in the include statement, I also had to name it as `include1` in the order statement.

Comment: Why do you even need the alias for?

Comment: In my project there was an alias, and it took me a while to debug why it wasn't working. So I wanted to save someone a bit of time.

Answer (score -1):

```
order:[
    [{ model: db.models.Product, as: 'include1' }, 
     { model: db.sequelize.models.ProductLanguage, as: 'include2' },
     'name',
     'desc']
```

After using this sequlizer is creating this in query. ORDER BY ``.`name` DESC LIMIT 10;

So how can I pass the table alias before name.